# Adding scalacheck to specs2+spray-testkit example

Tags: spray, specs2, scalacheck

Trying add scalacheck into the spray-testkit + specs2 example:
service with following route:

```
def myRoute = get(
  path("add" / IntNumber / IntNumber) ((a, b) =>
    complete((a+b).toString)
  )
)
```

and the test spec for it:

```
  "MyService" should {
    "do calculation" in {
      Get("/add/30/58") ~> myRoute ~> check {
        responseAs[String] === "88"
      }
    }
    "do calculation with scalacheck" in {
      check { (a: Int, b: Int) ⇒
        Get(s"/add/$a/$b") ~> myRoute ~> check {
          responseAs[String] === s"${a+b}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

should be pretty simple, but my brain is not allowed to formulate the second test case. i get error like

```
...MyService.Spec.scala:44: not found: value a"
 check { (a:Int, b:Int)
          ^
...MyService.Spec.scala:44: value ? is not a member of (Int, Int)
 check { (a:Int, b:Int) ?
                        ^
```

whats going on here and how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `=>` for the arrow instead of the unicode character `⇒`.

Then you should use `prop` instead of `check` and write:

```
"do calculation with scalacheck" in {
  prop { (a: Int, b: Int) =>
    Get(s"/add/$a/$b") ~> myRoute ~> check {
      responseAs[String] === s"${a+b}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, in the error message was no closing curly, my mistake

Comment: Can you try to use `=>` for the arrow instead of the unicode character `⇒`?

Comment: Yes it was! Probably IDEA makes that. Looks better now but now at "in" keyword: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.specs2.execute.AsResult[MyServiceSpec.this.RouteResult => ((Int, Int) => org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult[Any])]´

Comment: I think the issue comes from using `check`. See my edited answer.

Comment: how to import "prop"? from which namespace comes it from?

Comment: You get it if you extend the `org.specs2.ScalaCheck` trait on your specification. Also you need to make sure that you have the `specs2-scalacheck` jar on your classpath (and the `scalacheck` jar as well of course).

Comment: yes it works now! Thanks, couldn't figure it out without your help. Now the test works but fails after a few tries with Request was not handled but I think it is another problem

Comment: anyone, can you take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669605/request-was-not-handled-with-spray-testkit)? it drives me nuts