# Request was not handled with spray-testkit

Tags: scalacheck, spray-test, spec2, spray-routing

My service route:

```
get(
  path("add" / IntNumber / IntNumber)( (a, b) =>
    complete((a + b).toString())
  )
) ~
post(
  path("add") (
    formFields('a.as[Int], 'b.as[Int]) {
      (a, b) => complete((a + b).toString())
    })
)
```

my spec:

```
import spray.http.FormData

class RouteDefinitionSpec
  extends org.specs2.mutable.Specification
  with org.specs2.ScalaCheck
  with spray.testkit.Specs2RouteTest with RouteDefinition {

  def actorRefFactory = system

  "the route" should {
    "add with get requests" in {
      prop { (a: Int, b: Int) =>
        Get(s"/add/$a/$b") ~> route ~> check {
          responseAs[String] === s"${a+b}"
        }
      }
    }

    "add with post form data request" in {
      prop { (a: Int, b: Int) =>
        Post("/add", FormData(Seq("a" -> a.toString, "b" -> b.toString))) ~> route ~> check {
          responseAs[String] === s"${a+b}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Both GET and POST routes are working proper if tested in browser. The POST works also in test. 
What is wrong with my GET route? Why it can not be tested? What causes such an error and how to avoid it?

```
[info] RouteDefinitionSpec
[info]
[info] the route should
[error]   x add with get requests
[error]    Falsified after 0 passed tests.
[error]    > ARG_0: 2147483647
[error]    > ARG_1: -2147483648
[error]    > Request was not handled (RouteDefinitionSpec.scala:5)
[info]
[info]   + add with post form data request
[info]
[info]
[info] Total for specification RouteDefinitionSpec
[info] Finished in 393 ms
[info] 2 examples, 102 expectations, 1 failure, 0 error
```

**UPDATE:**
it seems something to do with scalacheck because following not-property-based test is also "green":

```
"add test without scalacheck" in {
  Get("/add/30/58") ~> route ~> check {
    responseAs[String] === "88"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same kind of error with my test code. Did you find the problem and if so can you post your solution ?

Comment: Still no solution. I have just commented out the failing tests

Comment: Can you try a "manual" test with the same arguments `2147483647` and `-2147483648`? Does `IntNumber` handle min and max values ok?

Comment: Argh... IntNumber matches only positive numbers. Thanks for the hint! CC @AntoineComte